# Formatting XML file

Tags: xml, unix, sed, awk, grep

Original Data :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CascadedExtractFileData>
<Country>
<IsoCountryCode>IN</IsoCo
untryCode>
<Provider>
<ItuCode>CASCADED_PROV</ItuCode>
<AccessInterconnect>
<CASCADE
D_INTERCONNECT_ID>50</CASCADED_INTERCONNECT_ID>
<TailTechnology>
<CASCADED_ACCESS_
METHOD_ID>1</CASCADED_ACCESS_METHOD_ID>
</TailTec
hnology></Access
Interconnect></
Provider><
/Country>
</C
ascad
edExtractFileData>
```

Required Like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CascadedExtractFileData>
<Country>
<IsoCountryCode>
IN
</IsoCountryCode>
<Provider>
<ItuCode>
CASCADED_PROV
</ItuCode>
<AccessInterconnect>
<CASCADED_INTERCONNECT_ID>
50
</CASCADED_INTERCONNECT_ID>
<TailTechnology>
<CASCADED_ACCESS_METHOD_ID>
1
</CASCADED_ACCESS_METHOD_ID>
</TailTechnology>
</AccessInterconnect>
</Provider>
</Country>
</CascadedExtractFileData>
```

I need each tag `<>` and `</>` on a new line and data in between `<>IN</>` e.g. `IN` also on a new line. I need a perfectly structured XML format.

I need a solution using Unix tools: `grep`, `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: if your system has `xmllint`, check its options. Many have options to reformat (indented), but that would be much easier to fix. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

this line will fix problems in your invalid xml file:

```
awk '{s=s $0}END{gsub(/></,">\n<",s);s=gensub(/>([^ \n>]*)</,">\n\\1\n<","g",s);print s}' file
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CascadedExtractFileData>
<Country>
<IsoCountryCode>
IN
</IsoCountryCode>
<Provider>
<ItuCode>
CASCADED_PROV
</ItuCode>
<AccessInterconnect>
<CASCADED_INTERCONNECT_ID>
50
</CASCADED_INTERCONNECT_ID>
<TailTechnology>
<CASCADED_ACCESS_METHOD_ID>
1
</CASCADED_ACCESS_METHOD_ID>
</TailTechnology>
</AccessInterconnect>
</Provider>
</country>
</cascadedExtractFileData>
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks for your reply..Can u please explain how it works.. I'm not getting :-(

Comment: Hi Kent...I am getting the following error while executing ..awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1

Comment: @user2202766 I took exactly same text in your question, and I got this output. you need gnu awk to run the line. my awk codes firstly handle empty elements, to put them in its new line. 2nd step I processed those tags with values.

Comment: Thanks Kent.. But my problem is a bit different than what you expected..if some data between the tags like <ex>example</ex> in this the text 'example' splits into two lines i need to combine it and place it in one line like <ex>\n example \n </ex> \n .. could please provide an idea for this ..

Comment: @user2202766 my awk line does that too. even if you have each char in one line, it will work without problem. because it does preprocessing, which means, it first put all your text into one line, then start processing. Therefore it doesn't matter how your input is separated into lines.

Comment: what is meant by {s=s $0} its giving error :-(

Comment: @user2202766 it turns your multi-line input into oneline text. you can change it into `s=s""$0`

Comment: can u pls give ur contact info where i can contact u if u dnt mind...

Comment: @user2202766 you have only 1 rep. not enough to chat.... sorry...

Comment: can i ping u in ur gmail or some where else ?

Comment: If you prefer the other way to communicate, what's your email?

Answer (score -1):

The following command removes the newline characters (to fix the XML tags) and then pipe the result to xmllint which can format the result:

```
cat data.xml | tr -d '\n' | xmllint -format -
```

Following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CascadedExtractFileData>
  <Country>
    <IsoCountryCode>IN</IsoCountryCode>
    <Provider>
      <ItuCode>CASCADED_PROV</ItuCode>
      <AccessInterconnect>
        <CASCADED_INTERCONNECT_ID>50</CASCADED_INTERCONNECT_ID>
        <TailTechnology>
          <CASCADED_ACCESS_METHOD_ID>1</CASCADED_ACCESS_METHOD_ID>
        </TailTechnology>
      </AccessInterconnect>
    </Provider>
  </Country>
</CascadedExtractFileData>
```

### Update

The format of my result file is not identical to your requirement, however I would submit it is more clearly formatted.

The xmllint program is very a useful tool when manipulating XML from the command-line. In addition to it's ability to validate and format XML it can also be used to search using [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

Comment: This doesn't fit the required output *(plus [UUoC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html))*

Comment: @sudo_O No need for insults. Your answer is no piece of genius either.

Comment: I don't see pointing out an incorrect answer as incorrect an insult!? Whether you think my answer is *genius* or not, it does what is required, unlike yours.

Comment: @sudo_O Let the person asking the question decide. Please let's keep it professional.

Comment: The person asking the question **clearly** specifies the format of the output. As per stackoverflow guidelines I down voted your answer because it doesn't do what is asked and left a comment as to why. I'm not sure why you are acting so defensively. The *professional* thing to do would be to fix your answer or remove it.

Comment: Revenge downvoting, how sad.